# MATLAB optimization: objective function with "steps"

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I am trying to find a minimum using fmincon in MATLAB, and I am facing a following problem:

*Optimization completed because the size of the gradient at the initial point 
is less than the default value of the function tolerance.*

My objective function's surface shows "steps", and therefore it has the same values over certain ranges of input variables (the size of the gradient is zero, if I am correct):

[image]

When moving from the initial point, the solver doesn't see any changes in the objective function's value, and finishes the optimization:

```
Iteration  Func-count       f(x)        Step-size       optimality

0           3          581.542                             0

Initial point is a local minimum.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient at the initial point 
is less than the default value of the function tolerance.
```

Is there any way make the solver move forward when the objective function keeps its value unchanged (until the objective function starts to increase)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably you would get reasonable results with a non-gradient based solver, e.g. [ga](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html), if the evaluation of the objective function is not costly. [how to choose solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/choosing-a-solver.html)

Comment: Thank you, guys. I followed your advice and used ga - the problem has gone! I also have studied your reference how to choose solver, and I realized, that I shouldn't use fmincon because my objective function is not smooth.

Comment: Great! I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post my extended comment as an answer in the hope that it will be easier for future answer seekers to find the solution:

Probably you would get reasonable results with a non-gradient based solver, e.g. [`ga`](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/genetic-algorithm.html), if the evaluation of the objective function is not costly. These are not dependent on the gradient and performing well on non-smooth functions.  It is also worth to read the following guide before selecting solver algorithm: [How to choose solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is right there :

`Initial point is a local minimum`.

The point you are giving as the **initial point** is already a **local minimum**. So the algorithm finds that minimum and sticks there.
In order to find other **local minimum** or maybe the **global** one, change the initial points to something else far from the **local minimum**.
In order to find the **global minimum** use a global optimization technique.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I can see the from the surface plot that the initial point is not local minimum (I used [0,0] as an initial point - I should have written it whendescribing my problem). Like Arpi wrote, it seems that I have to use another solver, as my objective function is non-smooth: it keeps the same value near the initial point (almost any point) (and the solver stucks there), and then changes its value like a Heaviside step function.

Comment: yes, GA (Genetic Algorithm) is a global optimization technique.